# How to install Emmet.zxp in Dreamweaver CC 2017?

Tags: dreamweaver

I had installed Emmet.zxp in Dreamweaver CC 2016 using ZXPInstaller but i cannot do it in Dreamweaver CC 2017.

I would like to use all the emmet commands, like "Merge Lines" and "Select Next Item".

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Emmet is already in dreamweaver 2017 by default

Comment: Yes I know that, but I want to use all the Emmet commands, like "Merge Lines" and "Select Next Item". Any idea on how to have them?